# Does the ".upper" function in a for loop, makes all of the letters upper and then change it back once it enters another if statement inside?

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop, if-statement

So I am following a Youtube guide about python coding and i'm just a little bit confused about the following code:

```
def translate(word):

    translation = ""

    for letter in word: 
        if letter.upper() in "AEIOU":
            if letter.islower():
                translation = translation + "r" 
            else:
                translation = translation + "R" 
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate("Hello World"))
#will print out “Hrllr Wrld”`
```

so it's a translation function where it will change all the vowels in a string into the letter 'r'. The part which is not clear to me is here:

```
if letter.upper() in "AEIOU":
        if letter.islower():
            translation = translation + "r" 
        else:
            translation = translation + "R" `
```

Shouldn't it be that all the vowels will be change into a capitalized 'R' because of the function "letter.upper()" even if the vowel that was in the string is not capitalized? and once that happens then wouldn't it be that python will never enter the "if letter.islower():" if statement?

Comment: `letter.upper()` does not convert your letter inplace but returns the result which is compared to 'AEIOU'. Your letter is still in lower case while you don't set it like `letter = letter.upper()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letter.upper()` does not change the value of `letter` variable. It simply returns a new (temporary and unnamed) variable that is an uppercase version of `letter`. You then test this new variable with `in` statement, but the `letter` variable is unchanged and can be used further.

For example, if `letter` was `'e'`, then `letter.upper()` returns `'E'`, but `letter` itself still remains `'e'`.

Comment: I see. Thank you clarifying it to me!

Answer (score 1):

In the first line - "if letter.upper() in "AEIOU":" the upper() converts each letter to uppercase and returns it to "if" operator. However, it does not saves the result in variable "letter"

Hence in second line - "letter.islower()" always check for it's initial case.

Example:

```
word = "Hello"
for letter in word:
    if letter.upper() in "AEIOU":
        print('The value of variable letter is ->', letter)
        temp = letter.upper()
        print('The value of variable temp is', temp)
```